# ¿Como suavizar los bordes de los objetos creados con WinAPI?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Estoy creando un boton personalizado que es un rectangulo con dos medios circulos uno a cada lado y el problema que tengo es que los circulos y las figuras con curvas por lo general se ven pixeladas y bastante feas. Aquí os dejo una foto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregunta es si hay alguna manera de hacer que se vea más nitido sin los bordes pixelados y sin usar una imagen como botón ya que me gustaría que pudiese cambiar su tamaño al aumentar el tamaño de la ventana.

De momento esto lo he hecho simplemente definiendo una region y poniendola como la region de una ventana hija que tiene un color de fondo morado y lo he hecho con el siguiente código:

```
   //TV es un struct que contiene el alto y el ancho de la ventana hija

    HRGN general;
    HRGN region1;
    HRGN region2;
    HRGN region3;

    general = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 0, 0);
    region1 = CreateRectRgn(TV.alto / 2, 0, TV.ancho - TV.alto/2, TV.alto);
    region2 = CreateEllipticRgn(0, 0, TV.alto, TV.alto);
    region3 = CreateEllipticRgn(TV.ancho - TV.alto, 0, TV.ancho, TV.alto);

    CombineRgn(general, region3, region2, RGN_OR);
    CombineRgn(general, region1, general, RGN_OR);

    SetWindowRgn(identificador, general, TRUE);
```

La parte que pone el fondo morado no la enseño y la letra S la podeis omitir que se me ha colado.

El objetivo es algo así (en cuanto a forma):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado mirando y creo que podría hacerlo con `Direct2D` o tambien puede que con `GDI+`. Con `Direct2D` he mirado que puedo hacer el dibujo con un objeto de tipo `ID2D1PathGeometry` El problema es que no se como adaptar la forma de la ventana al resulatado del dibujo (si alquien pudiese decirme como se hace el problema estaría resuleto).

Si pego demasiado la figura al borde termina teniedo el porde sin suavizado de la ventana y no se como poner con Direct2D un fondo de dibujo transparente sino que lo pone negro y acaba dando este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la figura la parte de abajo a la derecha se ve como queda si se pega demasiado al borde y arriba a la hizquierda se ve que el suavizado se ha hecho bien pero que el fondo se pinta negro en vez de pintar la ventana de detras.

Comment: porque nadie me responde :') decidme aunque sea que he hecho mal en la pregunta para poder cambiarlo (que ni con recompensa me responden )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estoy buscando diferentes maneras de hacerlo de momento he encontrado estas dos :

- Manera 1: Aunque la ventana la creo con el GDI y cambio la región de la ventana con el siguiente código:

```
HRGN general;
    HRGN region1;
    HRGN region2;
    HRGN region3;

    general = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 0, 0);
    region1 = CreateRectRgn(TV.alto / 2, 0, TV.ancho - TV.alto/2, TV.alto);
    region2 = CreateEllipticRgn(0, 0, TV.alto, TV.alto);
    region3 = CreateEllipticRgn(TV.ancho - TV.alto, 0, TV.ancho, TV.alto);

    CombineRgn(general, region3, region2, RGN_OR);
    CombineRgn(general, region1, general, RGN_OR);

    SetWindowRgn(identificador, general, TRUE);
```

Luego los gráficos los pinto con `Direct2D`. Para solventar el problema de que la parte en la que no pinta `Direct2D` se ve un fondo negro y no se permite la transparencia hago esto: Al crear la ventana del botón le aplico el estilo `WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP`

```
CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP, L"personalizada", texto.c_str(), WS_CHILD , posicion.X, posicion.Y, TV.ancho, TV.alto, IDpadre, (HMENU)identificador, GetModuleHandle(NULL), (LPVOID)this);
```

Despues inicializo los recursos graficos para poder pintar la ventana con Direct2D así:

```
   //Estas variables en el programa són globales
    ComPtr<ID3D11Device> direct3dDevice;

    ComPtr<IDXGIDevice> dxgiDevice;
    ComPtr<IDXGIFactory2> dxFactory;
    ComPtr<IDXGISwapChain1> swapChain;

    ComPtr<ID2D1Factory2> d2Factory;
    ComPtr<ID2D1Device1> d2Device;
    ComPtr<ID2D1DeviceContext> dc;

    ComPtr<IDXGISurface2> surface;
    ComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap1> bitmap;

    ComPtr<IDCompositionDevice> dcompDevice;
    ComPtr<IDCompositionTarget> target;
    ComPtr<IDCompositionVisual> visual;

    D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS const options = { D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL_INFORMATION };
    D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES1 properties = {};
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 description = {};

    /*la función HR la he creado antes 
      y sirve para confirmar que la función que se usa en los argumentos no falla.*/

    RECT rect = {};

    rect.left = 0;
    rect.top = 0;
    rect.bottom = TV.alto;
    rect.right = TV.ancho;

    description.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    description.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    description.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL;
    description.BufferCount = 2;
    description.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    description.AlphaMode = DXGI_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED;
    description.Width = rect.right - rect.left;
    description.Height = rect.bottom - rect.top;

    properties.pixelFormat.alphaMode = D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED;
    properties.pixelFormat.format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    properties.bitmapOptions = D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_TARGET | D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_CANNOT_DRAW;

    HR(D3D11CreateDevice(nullptr, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, nullptr, D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT, nullptr, 0, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &direct3dDevice, nullptr, nullptr));
    HR(direct3dDevice.As(&dxgiDevice));
    HR(CreateDXGIFactory2(DXGI_CREATE_FACTORY_DEBUG, __uuidof(dxFactory), reinterpret_cast<void**>(dxFactory.GetAddressOf())));
    HR(dxFactory->CreateSwapChainForComposition(dxgiDevice.Get(), &description, nullptr, swapChain.GetAddressOf()));

    HR(D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, options, d2Factory.GetAddressOf()));
    HR(d2Factory->CreateDevice(dxgiDevice.Get(), d2Device.GetAddressOf()));
    HR(d2Device->CreateDeviceContext(D2D1_DEVICE_CONTEXT_OPTIONS_NONE, dc.GetAddressOf()));
    HR(swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(surface), reinterpret_cast<void**>(surface.GetAddressOf())));
    HR(dc->CreateBitmapFromDxgiSurface(surface.Get(), properties, bitmap.GetAddressOf()));

    dc->SetTarget(bitmap.Get());

    HR(DCompositionCreateDevice(dxgiDevice.Get(), __uuidof(dcompDevice), reinterpret_cast<void**>(dcompDevice.GetAddressOf())));
    HR(dcompDevice->CreateTargetForHwnd(identificador, true, target.GetAddressOf()));
    HR(dcompDevice->CreateVisual(visual.GetAddressOf()));

    HR(visual->SetContent(swapChain.Get()));
    HR(target->SetRoot(visual.Get()));
```

Y lo unico que queda es en el mensaje `WM_PAINT` poner lo que se va a pintar usando `dc->BeginDraw()` y `HR(dc->EndDraw());` Entre estas dos hay que poner lo que se quiere pintar y el `Clear()` hace que el fondo sea completamente transparente:

```
    ID2D1SolidColorBrush *brush1;
          
        dc->BeginDraw();
        dc->Clear();

        D2D1_COLOR_F const brushColor = D2D1::ColorF(0.18f, 0.55f, 0.34f, 1);

        HR(dc->CreateSolidColorBrush(brushColor, &brush1));

        dc->FillGeometry(graficos,brush1);

        HR(dc->EndDraw());

        HR(swapChain->Present(1, 0));

        HR(dcompDevice->Commit());
```

Viene explicado con mucho detalle en este enlace: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/june/windows-with-c-high-performance-window-layering-using-the-windows-composition-engine

Este metodo tiene la 'desventaja' de que las zonas que son invisibles si que són pulsables por eso al principio hay que cambiar la region de la ventana.

Este es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Manera 2: Esta es más simple y por lo menos de momento parece que funciona mejor y más optimizado (viendo las herramientas de diagnostico de Visual Studio)

Consiste en dibujar los graficos de la ventana con `Gdiplus.h` usando en el objeto `Graphics` el metodo `SetSmoothingMode(Gdiplus::SmoothingModeAntiAlias);` así

```
    HDC HDc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    Gdiplus::SolidBrush pincel(color_fondo);
    Gdiplus::Pen boli(color_borde,borde);

    HDc = BeginPaint(identificador, &ps);//Empieza a pintar obteniendo un contexto de dispositivo

    Gdiplus::Graphics lienzo(HDc);//Creo un objeto para pintar con GDI++ con el contexto de dispositivo

    lienzo.SetSmoothingMode(Gdiplus::SmoothingModeAntiAlias); //Hago que los dibujos de GDI++ tengan suavizado de bordes
    //aqui tocaría dibujar algo
    EndPaint(identificador, &ps); //acabo el dibujo
```

Usando como pincel de fondo de la ventana el pincel `HOLLOW_BRUSH` obtenido con `GetStockObject(HOLLOW_BRUSH)` se consigue que el resto de la ventana que no se ha pintado sea transparente y que el fondo que hay detras del dibujo hecho con Direct2D también lo sea haciendo así que lo que se pinte con transparencia alfa se verá lo que hay detras de la ventana.

Con esto el dibujo se ve bien pero las esquinas que no están en el dibujo reciben eventos del ratón Para eso mejor que crear una region y ponerla como region de ventana que o se cargaría el dibujo (si está muy pegada) o dejaría un margen alrededor del dibujo donde se puede pulsar. Lo que he hecho es usar el mensaje  `WM_NCHITTEST` para las pruebas de impacto y con el siguiente codigo controlo en que parte de la ventana se puede hacer clic o no:

```
       case WM_NCHITTEST: //Esta es la parte que se encarga de controlar las pruebas de impacto

        POINTS puntos1 = MAKEPOINTS(lParam); //Se Captan las coordenadas de donde ha sido el clic
        POINT punto2;

        /*Se transforman las coordenadas(POINTS) a una variable de tipo POINT necesaria para Pasarlas a coordenadas
        relativas de pantalla a relativas del área de cliente de la ventana que es como están las coordenadas de la 
        region */

        punto2.x = puntos1.x;
        punto2.y = puntos1.y;


        ScreenToClient(identificador, &punto2); //se hace el intercambio de coordenadas relativas

        if (PtInRegion(general, punto2.x, punto2.y)) //se mira si la señal ha sido dentro de la region
        {
            return HTCLIENT; //Si está dentro dice que está en la region del cliente accepta el clic
        }
        else
        {
            return HTTRANSPARENT; //En el caso de que esté fuera hace como si no estuviese encima suyo y el mensaje pasa a la ventana de debajo.
        }

        break;
```

El significado de los valores que debuelve el procedimiento de ventana cuando le llega un mensaje `WM_NCHITTEST` viene bien explicado aquí: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-nchittest

Este es el resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]